# How do I make using Frameset like this?

Tags: html

How do I make something like this using only Frames & Framesets HTML. Dont mind The Y and B that will supposed to be what color in that frame.

Here What it should Look like:
[image: What it should Look like]

Comment: That is not possible, frames only support dividing a surface into **two or more columns side by side** and/or into **two or more rows underneath each other**. Your layout does not adhere to that rule. Also I'd like to mention that SO is not a write-my-code-for-me service. And framesets are obsolete in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Frames divide areas by drawing lines across an **entire** axis. Your design requires that they do not.